# How to solve the defining variables in bash prompt command not found the problem

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

My Linux distributions centeros7, define variables on the bash prompt command not found

```
[wanghao@localhost ~]$ al = nihao
bash: al: command not found...
[wanghao@localhost ~]$
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us i) the exact command you ran and ii) the exact error you received. Oh, and there's no such thing as centeros, you mean CentOS.

Comment: When I use Linux centeros when I define a variable is prompt command is not found

Comment: @terdon There is: http://www.centeros.com/. =) But he most probably means CentOS

Comment: Remove the spaces: `$ al=nihao`

Comment: @chaos wow, I stand corrected. Is that even a *nix? I can't tell from their webpage.

Comment: @terdon I have no idea... Just googled, seems like it's a webbased monitoring tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must not allow any spaces around the `=`

```
al=nihao
```

See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters

If you carefully read this section (http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Executing-Commands) you'll understand why "al" was being treated as a command.